# Store each line of text file into an array and remove \n

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I'd like to find the javascript/Jquery equivalent of this python code but I'm unable to :

`config_array = open("config.txt").read().splitlines()`

This opens the text file "config.txt" and stores each line into an array while removing '\n' at the end of line. For instance :

config.txt :

```
first line\n
second line\n
third line\n
```

gives me

```
config_array[0] == "first line"
config_array[1] == "second line"
config_array[2] == "third line"
```

How to achieve the same with javascript and Jquery ? Thanks

Comment: You will need to create an endpoint on your server which reads the contents of the txt file and returns it to the requestor. You can then `split()` the response to an array by the `\n`

Comment: Do you mean in a browser or using node.js? If you mean node, then it's very simple. In a browser, you'd need a lot more work to get access to the filesystem.

Comment: Are you want use it in node.js or browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be splitting the response from the file on `\n` see below
I assume that there are only three line in the file you are reading

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('your_file.txt', function (response) {
        a = response.split("\n");
        console.log(a[0], a[1], a[2]);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with ajax.

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", file, false);
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(txtFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(txtFile.status === 200 || txtFile.status == 0)
            {
                var result = txtFile.responseText;
                result.split("\n");
                console.log(result);

            }
        }
    }
    txtFile.send(null);
}
readTextFile('path to txt file')
```

Answer (score 0):

You do like below

```
var myArray = new Array;
$.get('example.txt', function(data) {
   //Bind in div
   $('#div').html(data.replace('\n',''));
    //insert in Array
    myArray = data.split('\n');
});
```

Comment: why the "div binding" line ?

Comment: Its not binding line, Its replacing the '\n' and bind the text in the div.

Comment: It's not working, every value in the array is "undefined" or empty

Answer (score 0):

The OP requires reading from a text file and removing the string '\n'. Thus,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       function readTextFile(file) {
            const rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            let content = null;
            rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
                    if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0) {
                        content = rawFile.responseText;
                    }
                }
            };
            rawFile.send(null);
            return content;
        }

        let textFile = 'config.txt';
        // read text file
        let rtf = readTextFile(textFile);
        // replace string \n 
        let rnl = ta.replace(/\\n/g, '');
        // store each line in an array
        console.log(rnl.split('\n'));
}
```